# Cross Site Scripting (XSS): Do I need to escape the ampersand?

Tags: escaping, xss, ampersand

I want to escape for XSS in an HTML context, and so far I treat the `<`, `>`, and `"` characters.
Apparently it is recommended to escape the ampersand as well, but why? (Other than for keeping the HTML valid, let's assume that this is not an issue)

So what I am asking is:
When I escape `<`, `>` and `"`, can someone demonstrate how the ampersand can still allow an XSS attack in an HTML context?

Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should really take a look at the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet.

You should escape & because it can be used to circumvent other defenses. Consider this code:

```
<button onclick="confirm('Do you really want to delete <%= data_from_user; %> ?'">Delete</button>
```

To defend against XSS inside the onclick event handler, the developer escapes ', ", < and > in data_from_user and thinks everything is ok. The problem is that if the attacker types `&#39;` which passes the escaping, but ends up allowing the attacker to run javascript.

Example here: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=124

Comment: Interesting example, cheers!
What I tried was to inject this into the html:
&#60;script type="text/javascript"&#62;
Which does not get executed, howerver displayed as "<script.."

Comment: Note that in the linked example, the attacker is not described as typing `&#39`; the attacker is described there as having typed in `Joe');alert('XSS` and the site made that `Joe&#39;);alert(&#39;XSS`, which was not correct escaping, because that escaped it as far as the HTML was concerned, but apostrophes were still being passed to the JS engine. It's true if an "&" was allowed to get through, the attacker could type it themselves, but the issue being focused on there is that (as mentioned in the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet), event-handler attribute text should be *JS*-escaped (\xHH).

Comment: ...for that matter, the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet [actually advises \xHH escaping **all** non-alphanumeric chars with ASCII values < 256](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values)... just in case a careless dev uses an unquoted attribute somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

you use & to concatenate params in the URL:

**Reflected XXS**:
Script code is injected in the URL which the webpage reflects to victims

> http://mybank.com/page?message= < script src = “evil _script.js” />

Comment: I did not downvote, but I don't see how the URL with the injected message relates to the ampersand. More: in the case of URL query assembling escaping doesn't help, the ampersand in URL parameter needs to be url encoded.