# Is the '&' character safe against xss attacks?

Tags: html, security, xss

I wonder if the character `&` is safe to be output to a browser. In case `'<' '>' '\'' '\"' '='` are all encoded,

> is there a possibility to get damaged by an attack if '&'isn't
>   encoded?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124134/cross-site-scripting-xss-do-i-need-to-escape-the-ampersand and the comments

Comment: @ArmandGrillet, thanks. That's what i asked. I searched previously, but as i didn't look for "ampersand" I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not safe, you should escape it. You can see an example of exploiting XSS using `&` here: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=124