# url_for creates a url query string with &amp;

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, query-string

Lets say i have the following script in a html template of a flask application

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log('{{ url_for('root', arg1='hello', arg2='world') }}')
<script>
```

and i have a flask endpoint root()

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def root():
  print(print(request.args))
```

when i call my page the internal script is rendered to

```
console.log('/api/art_structure?arg2=world&amp;arg1=hello')
```

When I call this url my `request.args` dict is:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('amp;arg1', 'hello'), ('arg2', 'world')])
```

Which is not correct since the key of `arg1` is wrong.
Any clues how I can prevent jinja2 from converting `&` to `&amp;`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The ampersand**

The correct URL is `/api/art_structure?arg2=world&arg1=hello`.

The problem with the above URL is that ampersand (`&`) cannot be written directly in HTML, because the ampersand is used for entity references. For example, to write `<` character in HTML, which is not a tag start, one can write `&lt;`. Because of that, to write `&`, one should *escape* it, i.e. write it as `&amp;`.

Jinja2 templating engine does that by default. So, you can dump the contents of any string variable even if it contains special characters and they will be correctly escaped, e.g. `&` will become `&amp;` as in your case.

**How does that work?**

So, if you actually put this in your jinja template: `<a href="{{ url_for('root', arg1='hello', arg2='world') }}">link</a>`, it would write the following HTML code: `<a href="/api/art_structure?arg2=world&amp;arg1=hello">link</a>`, and if you clicked on the link in the browser, it would correctly replace `&amp;` with `&` and open `/api/art_structure?arg2=world&arg1=hello`.

(note, however, that writing plain `&` as it is into HTML may sometimes also work, because browsers may guess how to fix the error)

**So why does it not simply work in this case?**

Because you are generating JavaScript and not HTML (you are generating code within `<script>` and `</script>`. In JavaScript, `&` is fine and should not be escaped, so you are free to write it as it is. To tell Jinja that you do not want it to *escape* the string, you can use the `safe` filter, i.e. `{{ url_for('root', arg1='hello', arg2='world') | safe}}`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `safe`

**Ex:**

```
console.log("{{ url_for('root', arg1='hello', arg2='world') | safe}}")
```

**[MoreInfo](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#safe)**

Comment: Although a _MoreInfo_ link is somewhat useful, it would be better to explain in the answer itself what `&amp;` is, why jinja creates it, why it is wrong within `<script>` block and what `safe` does.

Comment: Don't use `| safe` with `url_for` as it potentially allows for XSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39246205/3812928

Comment: @NotoriousPyro That link says nothing about `url_for`, or about escaping JavaScript code. It is about escaping user input (or other external data) when generating HTML (using JavaScript, but that is not the point). `url_for` is a flask function and I don't see how it could be hijacked for XSS.

Comment: Because if you use `| safe` with`url_for` you will end up stopping un-escaping that `url_for` does. Since `url_for` can end up with user-inputted data, it is possible that it will end up with XSS. E.g. you allow the user to submit a form and you generate a url on the target page using their form data but you escaped `url_for`...

Comment: You should **not** need to use `| safe` with `url_for`. If you need to use it inside a script, you should be careful what data is allowed to make it into that call to `url_for`.